# How to restrict access to spcecific attribute of strapi collection?

Tags: strapi

I have created a collection type that represents "question".
the type has these attributes:

- title: string
- content: string
- email: email
- answered: boolean

I am going to make a call to this collection endpoint from two places in my front-end website:

1. from Questions page and in this case I want to collection endpoint not to send the "email" of the user who raised the question
2. from admin page, where authenticated users can see the email of the person who raised the question.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?